# Access is changing the field name in export to csv

Tags: ms-access, field-names

When I export an Access table to a .csv file, it changes the field names replacing the # with a period.  For example, the field "Name#1" becomes "Name.1".  The application that will be ingesting the output file requires the # instead of the period.  How can I either prevent this or rename the column header in the output?

I am using Access 2013.

Per request, here is the code:

Dim strPath As String

strPath = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\Test"

DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "Customer_Info", strPath, True

Comment: HOW do you export to CSV? You may have to write your own export function.

Comment: Well, that's another reason why it is bad idea to use punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Very unfortunate the other app is also using. Edit question to provide your code. Edit the csv file in Excel or Notepad.